# Zapier to Twilio to generate Dynamic SMS body

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, zapier

I would like to use Zapier to send an SMS via Twilio with a dynamic body containing different affiliate referral link to an app every time I get a new subscriber to my mailchimp mailing list.

I have two separate bits of code that do what I am looking for but, due to the limitations of installing modules within the code automation in Zapier and my lack of experience in programming i dont know how to bring the two together in a Zapier code Zap.

This is the code I can use to send an SMS with Twilio and works fine independently:

```
const accountSid = '<twilioAcctSid>';
const authToken = '<twilioAuthToken>';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
  .create({from: '<twilPhoneNo>', body: '<affiliateRefLink>', to: '<subscriberPhoneNo>' })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
  .done();
```

This is the code I have used elsewhere to randomly select one of my affiliate links and I would like include a random link in the body of the SMS to the new subscriber.

```
const refCodes = ['link1',
                'link2',
                'link3'];

function getCode()
{
    let randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * refCodes.length));
    let baseSite = "#url_";
    let newLink = baseSite + refCodes[randomNum];
    document.getElementById('#url').href = newLink;
    document.getElementById('#url').innerHTML = newLink;

}
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Toes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @philnash for your support, I was able to solve this with the code below!

```
  exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const appCodes = ['code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4']
  var smsBody = refCode ();
  var subNum = event.primaryPhone || 'There is no subscriber number'; // primaryPhone sent via HTTP post to twilio function

function refCode () {
    return appCodes[Math.floor((Math.random() * appCodes.length))];
};

  context.getTwilioClient().messages.create({
    to: `${subNum}`, // parameters & values recieved from HTTP POST are available within the twilio functions "event" context
    from: '+1444555666',
    body: `Get the App: ${smsBody}`
  }).then(msg => {
    callback(null, msg.sid);
  }).catch(err => callback(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure you can run custom code like that within Zapier. However, what I might suggest is that you use the [Zapier webhook module](https://zapier.com/page/webhooks/) combined with a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions).

Twilio Functions give you a serverless way of running custom Node.js based code, so you could combine the two pieces of code you have above in one Function that is then called by the Zapier webhook. Alternatively, if MailChimp allow you to setup your own webhooks you could circumvent Zapier entirely and point it straight at your Twilio Function.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: David here, from the Zapier Platform team. This sounds like a great approach! One point of clarification - Zapier code steps can't use external node modules (such as `twilio`) but custom [CLI apps](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) can! You could make `my great twilio CLI app` that runs whatever you need with whatever modules.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback guys, sincerely appreciated! I will look further into the above information!!!